# How can I find two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = -BA$ and $AB \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need help in finding two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that

$AB = -BA$ also $AB \neq 0$

Comment: What are your thoughts? You should add your attempts at a solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: Why put on hold this issue ?  Already there are several answers, of which the frankly happy one of Baymax. Curiously, when the question is: "find $A,B$ s.t. $AB-BA=I$" or "$AB=I$ implies $BA=I$", then it is never put on hold (and yet, they are often asked). It is true that this kind of questions makes it easy to earn points; but I want to believe that this is not the only reason

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is invertible this means that $ABA^{-1}=-B$, so $B$ and
$-B$ are conjugates. Thus I would try for my $B$ a matrix like
$$\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

An example with two invertible matrices:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{give}\quad AB=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\quad BA=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take for example $A,B \in M(2,\mathbb{R})$.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} \\ B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you find these two matrices?

Comment: I've just searched for a matrix which changes the sign of my entries if multiplied left and right.

Answer (score 0):

$AB = - BA$ , now if matrix $AB$ is invertible then  $det (AB) = -det(BA)$ implying that $2 det(A)det(B) = 0$.

So atleast one of the matrices is singular! .  and $Trace(AB) = - Trace(BA) $ also we know that $Trace(AB) = Trace(BA)$ , so $2.Trace(AB) = 0$ , implying Trace of the matrix $AB$ and $BA$ and also $-BA $ is zero!

Doodling around will give you the matrices say for example as by 
Alberto Andrenucci.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} \\ B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Also now you can vary the entries of the matrix and create new ones keeping the conditions in the first two lines in mind :)

Comment: Your initial assertion is wrong: I posted an example with two invertible matrices.

Comment: I also need to ask one more question, is there any relation between Trace(A) and Trace(B)?

Comment: Just did an edit,is it correct now ?@Bernard

Comment: @MSA [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dnett/S611/15Trace.pdf)

Comment: Take into account that  $\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$ ( $n$-dimension) so for $n=2$  $\det(A)=\det(-A)$